# Need to find radius and interval of convergence for following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(2x+4)^n}{n+1}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Having trouble finding the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for this question. I did the ratio test and I'm left with this.

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{(2x+4)(n+1)}{n+2}\right|
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq2A}$$

Not sure what to do from here. Is the radius of convergence 1?

Comment: First of all, put absolute values around everything. What is the limit as $n\to \infty$? What does the ratio test say the limit needs to be for convergence?

Comment: @zugzug ratio test says its gotta be less than one, but this is one

Comment: It's not equal to one. Think of $|2x+4|$ as just a number. With respect to $n$, it remains constant in the limit. The whole point is to solve for $x$ that satisfy the inequality dictated by the ratio test.

Comment: @zugzug what's the inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series converges if $|2x+4| <1$ and diverges for $|2x+4| >1$. The interval of convergence is $[-5/2,-3/2)$. [The series diverges at the right end point and converges at  the left end point].

Comment: thank you homie i love u. now i understand. learning by example homezz